# How can I change backspace to '\b'?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I see a question in *[The C Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)*. It's like this:
Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each tab by \t , each backspace by \b , and each backslash by \ . This makes tabs and backspaces visible in an unambiguous way.

Then I write a program like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(c=='\t')
        {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('t');
        }
        if(c=='\b')
        {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('b');
        }
        if(c=='\\')
        {

            putchar('\\');
            putchar('\\');
        }
        else{
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I input backspace, I can't get '\b', so how can I get the output '\b'? I.e., I mean, how can I output backspace?

Comment: what do you get as output? Does tab behave correctly?

Comment: I don't think there is one simple answer to this. It depends on your terminal etc - it may be buffering up everything you type and then sending it to your program when you hit enter. If this is the case it may process backspace for you and your program will never see them.

Comment: I believe `puts` may be more efficient, such as `puts("\\t");`.  It replaces two function calls with one.

Comment: A `switch` statement would be more readable, IMHO.

Comment: Your `else` is only tied to the last `if`, so you're printing the original character after the escape sequence for '\t' and '\b'... so the actual backspace character is probably eating the 'b' after you've printed it.

Answer (score 7):

Keyboard input is preprocessed by the operating system. Most characters are fed directly as input to your program, but some are handled specially.

On UNIX-like systems, standard input is usually line-buffered. The system reads a whole line of text and doesn't pass it on to your program until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  While reading that line, the system processes <kbd>Backspace</kbd> itself; rather than adding a backspace character to the buffer, it erases the most recent character. Your program never sees the `'\b'` character.

To enter a literal backspace character that can be seen by your program, on a UNIX-like system you can precede it with Ctrl-V.  And depending on your tty and terminal emulator settings, typing the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key might transmit an ASCII DEL character rather than backspace. To make sure your program sees a backspace character, type <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd>.

On non-UNIX-like systems (most likely Windows), there's probably a way to do something similar, but I don't know what it is.

You can also run your program with input from a file. Getting a literal backspace character into the input file is left as an exercise (it depends on the workings of your text editor).

Comment: Nice answer and you can use `getch()` to detect each key press

Comment: @Ludovic: There are at least two functions called `getch`. One is Windows-specific; the other is part of [n]curses.

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you ! i will try to improve my answer

Comment: Thank you @KeithThompson, both Ctrl-Backspace and Ctrl-V followed by Ctrl-H worked for me on Ubuntu, but Ctrl-V followed by Backspace gives a `^?` (I think that's the ASCII DEL?)

Comment: @user51462 That's to be expected. The "Backspace" key can be configured (typically in your terminal emulator settings) to send either Backspace (ASCII code 8, "^H") or DEL (ASCII code 127, "^?"). Ctrl-H should always send a backspace character, regardless of terminal settings.

Answer (score 2):

The `getchar` function buffers the user input and sends it to your program only when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. As suggested, you must use `getch()` to detect each keypress.

Your code must be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getch()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\t')
        {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('t');
        }
        else if (c == '\b')
        {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('b');
        }
        else if (c == '\\')
        {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('\\');
        }
        else if (c == '\r')
        {
            putchar('\n');
        }
        else{
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd> is detected as `\r` by *getch*, so you have to manually replace it by `\n` if you want to go to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The backspace is usually eaten up by the shell. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to test for backspace.

See *[5. Delete and Backspace](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html)* for more detail.

Comment: That works only if your configuration cause the Backspace key to send a DEL character.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have three `if`s with only one *else* at the end... so your *else* is only tied to the last `if`.  For tab and backspace, since they're not a backslash, the last `if` test is false, and the `else` block executes printing the original character.  This means after printing '\t' you print a tab (and likely see some empty space in your output), and after printing '\b' you print a backspace which eats the 'b' or causes it to get overwritten by the next character.  To fix it, either use:

```
    if(c == '\t')
    {
        putchar('\\');
        putchar('t');
    }
    else if(c=='\b')    /* "else if" rather than "if" */
    {
        putchar('\\');
        putchar('b');
    }
    else if(c=='\\')
    {
        putchar('\\');
        putchar('\\');
    }
    else{
        putchar(c);
    }
```

...or simply rewrite it with a switch:

```
    switch(c)
    {
        case '\t':
            puts("\\t");
            break;
        case '\b':
            puts("\\b");
            break;
        case '\\':
            puts("\\\\");
            break;
        default:
            putchar(c);
    }
```